# yii2 rest api sign up post request values is empty

Tags: php, json, yii2, rest

I'm writing rest api to register a user for the first time and for some reason POST sends an empty request, although I specify in postman the indexes I need. My controller code. When i var_dump($_POST) is empty [].

```
public function actionSignup()
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $model = new UserData();
    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        $model->email = $_POST['email'];
        $model->password = $_POST['password'];
        $model->phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $model->name = $_POST['name'];
        $model->surname = $_POST['surname'];
        if ($model->validate()) {
            $model->save();
            Yii::$app->response->setStatusCode(201);
            return 'ok';
        } else {
            Yii::$app->response->setStatusCode(422);
            return $model->getErrors();
        }
    }
}
```

The configuration I put in web.php

```
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'enableCsrfValidation' => false,
        'parsers' => [
            'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
        ],],
```

My user model

```
class UserData extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {
public static function tableName()
{
    return '{{%user}}';
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['email', 'password', 'name', 'surname', 'phone'], 'required'],
        [['email', 'password', 'name', 'token', 'surname'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['phone'], 'string', 'max' => 11],
        ['email', 'email'],
    ];
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'email' => 'Email',
        'password' => 'Password',
        'name' => 'Name',
        'token' => 'Token',
        'surname' => 'Surname',
        'phone' => 'Phone',
    ];
}
```

I don't understand what the mistake is.. On the Yii forum I found only one answer similar to my problem, but that doesn't work either. This is my first time asking a question, I hope I got it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using parsers doesn't mean the `$_POST` variable will get filled. You need to access post data using `yii\web\Request` methods like `post()` or `getBodyParams()`.

For example you can change assigning to model properties like this:

```
$model->email = Yii::$app->request->post('email');
```

Or to load all properties in one line:

```
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(), '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be the main cause is `contentType`, which should be `contentType: "application/json;"` in your ajaxCall.

By default contentType is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;`, so that can be access with `Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams()` in controller action.

Sample AjaxCall:

```
    $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'actionURL',
    data: JSON.stringify(sendInfo),
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (exception) {
        console.log(exception);
    }
});
```